# Magento 2.2.5 : public function getConfiguredAmount(): \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface

Tags: php, php-7, magento-2.2.5, magento-core

From this `\vendor\magento\module-wishlist\Pricing\ConfiguredPrice\ConfigurableProduct.php`

File I find below code:

```
public function getConfiguredAmount(): \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item\Option $customOption */
        $customOption = $this->getProduct()->getCustomOption('simple_product');
        $product = $customOption ? $customOption->getProduct() : $this->getProduct();
        return $product->getPriceInfo()->getPrice(ConfiguredPriceInterface::CONFIGURED_PRICE_CODE)->getAmount();
    }
```

What the below code mean

**public function getConfiguredAmount(): \Magento\Framework\Pricing\Amount\AmountInterface**

Comment: Please check my answer, also let me know if there is need to expand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a new feature in **PHP 7** called **Return type declarations**.

> Return type declarations specify the type of the value that will be
>   returned from a function. The same types are available for return type
>   declarations as are available for argument type declarations.

Relevant for your given code ;

> When overriding a parent method, the child's method must match any
>   return type declaration on the parent. If the parent doesn't define a
>   return type, then the child method may do so.

You can read it more in new features notes -  [here](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.return-type-declarations)

and detailed official documentation - [here](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php#functions.returning-values.type-declaration)

Please don't hesitate to ping me in case of confusion.